# Javascript Will not return Contents of JSON File stored

Tags: javascript, json, error-handling, undefined

I am working on a small script that is supposed to take information from a JSON file and use that info to populate a table in my webpage. I am writing a script from a Youtube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12tjh_6xL2M), below is the code I have as given in the tutorial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const rankingsBody = document.querySelector("#rankings-table > tbody");

        function loadRankings() {
            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.open("get", "data/rankings.json");

            request.onload = () => {
                try {
                    const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    populateRankings(json);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.warn("Could not load rankings");
                }
            };

            request.send();
        }


        function populateRankings (json) {
            console.log(json);
        }

        console.log(request);
    </script>
```

Now, the console.log() function at the end of the script is supposed to print the contents of the JSON file to the console, upon checking in Firefox, it does not print and throws the following error error:

> ReferenceError: request is not defined

And when I try to run the *loadRankings* function in the console, it says it is undefined, So, I guess its not returning the data as expected because it hasn't been defined?

I am not really sure what the problem could be, could you help me to figure this one out? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Why would you expect `console.log(request)` to print the contents of the file? `request` is an `XMLHttpRequest` object, not the file contents.

Comment: `populateRankings()` prints the contents of the file, why do you need `console.log(request)`?

Comment: I wanted to use the browser console to see if the function works

Comment: Make `json` a global variable instead of a local variable, then you can type `console.log(json)` in the console.

Comment: Doesn't `console.log(json);` serve that purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You declared `request` in `loadRankings()`.  Then you tried to print it outside of the context where it exists with `console.log(request);`  [const declarations are not hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), so you get a reference error.  Either move the declaration to the global scope like this so it's visible to your console.log() statement:

```
    const rankingsBody = document.querySelector("#rankings-table > tbody");
    let globalRequest;

    function loadRankings() {

        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Expose the most recent request in the global variable
        globalRequest = request;

        request.open("get", "data/rankings.json");

        request.onload = () => {
            try {
                const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                populateRankings(json);
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn("Could not load rankings");
            }
        };

        request.send();
    }


    function populateRankings (json) {
        console.log(json);
    }

    console.log(globalRequest);
```

or just remove the console.log() statement entirely.